# Deterministic Finite Automaton with Prolog

Tags: prolog, state-machine

I'm trying to create a Deterministic Finite Automaton(DFA) with Prolog but I'm stuck. I didn't have this problem with Haskell, so I would highly appreciate any help. So far, here is what I've done:

```
start(q1).
final(q4).
transition(q1, '.', q3).
transition(q1, '0', q2).
transition(q1, '1', q2).
transition(q2, '.', q4).
transition(q2, '0', q2).
transition(q2, '1', q2).
transition(q3, '.', q5).
transition(q3, '0', q4).
transition(q3, '1', q4).
transition(q4, '.', q5).
transition(q4, '0', q4).
transition(q4, '1', q4).
transition(q5, '0', q5).
transition(q5, '1', q5).

accept(symbols, startState).

dfaAccept(symbols) :-
   start(startstate).
dfaAccept([], State) :-
   final(State).
dfaAccept([Symbol|Symbols], State) :-
   transition(State, Symbol, NextState),
   accept(Symbols, NextState).
```

When I run

```
dfaAccept(df1, "1.01").
```

I should get true, but I'm getting false ....

Comment: Related: https://github.com/l-flat/lflat

Answer (score 1):

I think [DCGs](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) are even better way to represent FSMs, but let's talk syntax:

You call

```
dfaAccept(df1, "1.01").
```

but predicate `dfaAccept/2` expects the arguments in reverse order:

```
dfaAccept([Symbol|Symbols], State)
```

`df1` is also not mentioned again.

Then "1.01" may or may not be a "list of character (atoms of length 1)" depending on your Prolog. If it's SWI Prolog, you have to transmogrify it first using [`atom_chars/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_chars/2).

And what is `accept(symbols, startState).` for? It's hanging around all by its lonesone.